# How to export your location as WGS84 in a new string

Tags: java, android, coordinate, wgs84

I'm making a new private android app to take a picture, get your current location in WGS84, and at last send it all in an e-mail to your self.

I have send the mail with the content from the textfields, but I have made a button to get the your current location, but didn't know how to get your location and in same way also convert it to WGS84. I need to get it in this coordinatesystem, because it is used in a special sparetime activity, which uses this coordinatesystem.

Just forget the picture, the coordinate is more important.

Thanks in advance

Greetings Aksel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I got your question right. But you want to convert the location you get into WGS84 coordinatesm right? I'll guess you get your position via the Android LocationManager using something like:  `LocationManager.getLastPosition()`. What you get is a [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) . This location can be formated in different ways.

The questions is what exactly do you want? WGS84 is a reference system and does not say anything about the way coordinates are represented. A common representation are sphereical coordinates (also called Lat/Lon coordinates): [Spherical Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Another representation would be [Cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). Maybe thats what you are looking for. To get cartesian coordinates you should use a 3rd party library.